# Multiple requests to OSRM at once (using docker)

Tags: performance, geo, osrm

I would like to push multiple requests to the OSRM backend (see https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend) at once. Currently, for me to get the distance between two points, I do something like this:

```
curl "http://127.0.0.1:5000/route/v1/driving/10,50;13,52?overview=false"
```

However, I need to do this for more than 2m rows... So I would like to know if I can send the docker image multiple requests at the same time?

Or if anyone has a better idea, it would be great!

Comment: Is `r` relevant here?

Comment: @Christoph indeed, it is true. I changed it. I am just so used to adding r as a tag

Comment: From [here](http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.7.0/api/#route-service) it seems you can send several points at once, but I don't know whether that is fast.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the [table service](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/blob/master/docs/http.md#table-service) which allows you to compute many-to-many queries and returns the duration between each pair. (also allows for asymmetric tables if you need that)

Other then that, keep in mind OSRM is already multi-threaded. If you send multiple HTTP requests at the same time it will use all available cores on your system to compute those queries.

If the HTTP layer is too much overhead, you could try our [node bindings](http://npmjs.org/package/osrm) or write your own C++ code and link against `libosrm`.